# Variable Trouble in Worksheets()

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I am writing an excel macro that is designed to cycle through worksheets copying sections and pasting them in a different workbook with the same worksheet names. Each actual sheet name stands for a friday in the quarter (13 sheets), so tomorrow is 071114 for July 11th, 2014.

I have set a vba variables week1 - week13 to those tab names. I want the For loop below to cycle through week1 to week13, but it isn't working the way I want it to because the computer is searching for a tab named "week1" instead of the variable week1. I think I am going to just change the tab names, but I was wondering for future reference if there is a way to do this.

```
For x = 1 To 13
    wbD.Activate
    Worksheets("week" & x).Activate
    Range(carange).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wbC.Activate
    Worksheets("week" & x).Activate
    Range(carange).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use arrays for that. Just like below. Have not tested it yet, but should give you an idea what I am talking about.

```
Public Sub TestArray()

    Dim wkSheetNames(13) As String

    wkSheetNames(1) = "Some Name"
    wkSheetNames(2) = "Some Name"
    wkSheetNames(3) = "Some Name"
    '.................
    '.................
    wkSheetNames(12) = "Some Name"
    wkSheetNames(13) = "Some Name"


    For x = 1 To 13
        wbD.Activate
        Worksheets(wkSheetNames(x)).Activate
        Range(carange).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wbC.Activate
        Worksheets(wkSheetNames(x)).Activate
        Range(carange).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next x


End Sub
```

Thanks,
V

Comment: +1 for storing the names in an array, could be stored in a global variable if the worksheet names are used in several scripts

Answer (score 2):

@Vikas' solution, which uses an array to store the worksheet names as `String` variables, is a great recommendation. Since your `Workbook` and `Range` variables also appear to be defined, you could further refine your macro by avoiding the `.Activate` and `.Select` methods, two common sources of run-time errors, and instead using the `Range.Copy` method:

```
'note: if carange is a named range defined in the worksheets, this code would
'need to be adjusted to ...Range("carange").Copy...
For x = 1 To 13
    wbD.Worksheets(wkSheetNames(x)).Range(carange).Copy _
        Destination:=wbC.Worksheets(wkSheetNames(x)).Range(carange)
Next x
```

Here's an MSDN link to the `Range.Copy` method with more examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx

Here's a super-informative post with recommendations on how to avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Thanks Dan. I will definitely check those out. Typing Activate a lot is annoying....

Comment: Truly -- and it's even MORE annoying when it causes on error! The linked S.O. post in my response is worth bookmarking, trust me :)

Comment: Hey @Dan, I tried your code on a different part of my process and it doesn't seem to be working for me. I was wondering if you could help out.

`For y = 1 to 13
   For x = 1 To 50
      wbC.Worksheets(week(y)).Range(rangepl(x)).Copy _
      Destination:=wbA.Worksheets(week(y)).Range(rangefc(x))
   Next x
Next y`

The rangepl and rangefc are arrays where

`Dim rangepl(50) As Range`
`Set rangepl(1) = Range("B4:AS4")`

Comment: Hey @Aubrey I think the community can definitely help out here, but it looks like this is a new situation warranting a new question. Would you please add your code and a short write-up on the new task and where you are getting the error?